# jQuery isotope filtering from fetching data from url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on jquery isotopes, and there is data filtering in same page like on details.php

```
<div class="sorting-tags">
  <div class="filter" data-filter="all"> All </div>
  <div class="filter " data-filter=".product-electronics"> electronics </div>
  <div class="filter " data-filter=".product-sports"> Sports</div>
</div>

<div class="project-item mix product-sports">
  <div class="project">
    <!-- other code -->
  </div>
</div>
```

This is working as this is in same page but there is need of filtering data based on url

product.php

```
<a href="details.php?product=electronics" data-filter=".product-sports">Sports</a>
```

So when click url becomes `details.php?product=electronics` and can get data from url as `$_GET['product']`

Answer (score 0):

How about adding some PHP code to isotope initialization? Something like this

Add this to the top of your page

```
<?php
  $filter = isset($_GET['product']) ? '.' . $_GET['product'] : '';
?>
```

in javascript add isotope like this

```
$('...').isotope({ filter: '<?=$filter;?>' });
```